# iOS Background threading Class

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

Is there a way to dispatch every method of certain class on specific thread?
I want to run every method of a certain class asynchronously on background thread without adding

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
// code
}
```

to every method. Which method of `NSObject` should I override?

Comment: No, there is not. Maybe you could swizzle every method in your class, but 1. You should subclass from NSObject, and every method should be dynamic. 2. Seems like you should use NSInvocation, but you can't use it in Swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds unnecessary (and probably a bad idea). If it were possible (which it probably isn't) it would mean every single method would require a completion block in order to return anything, even private functions.

The better way to do this is to have most of your methods private, and have a few public methods as vectors into the class that call async.

If you want to avoid all the syntax, you could do something like this:

```
let BA = { (block: @escaping () -> ()) in
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(execute: block)
    }

BA {
    // do whatever
}
```

And if you want to do it for the entire function you could do:

```
func doSomething() { BA {

}}
```

Comment: Thank you, the block solution will suffice. 
I'm developing a framework, so I didn't want to block main thread and do all the stuff on background.